# Hide a UIImageview in UITableView Custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Iam trying to hide a `UIImageView` in `UITableView` cell ,if the device is in `iOS 6.0` + version. and i wanna show the `UIImageView` if the device using `iOS 6.0` or lower version ?

Below code is not working for me.I can see the `UIImage` in both versions.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",recentBookName);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    GMMListViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.NameLabel.text=[BookName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.authorLabel.text=[AuthorName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] floatValue]<6.0){
        cell.rupeeSymbol.hidden=NO;

    }else{
     cell.rupeeSymbol.hidden=YES;

    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and make sure rupeeSymbol has value? Sometimes we do forget to link the outlet against the nib.

Comment: Which versions are you testing it in?

Comment: Try `if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] floatValue]<6.0f){
}`

Answer (score 4):

Add following code

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

To your `projectName-Perfix.pch` file so you can access it from anywhere in your project.

This above code is for no need to do extra repeat work.

And just put condition such like *(Anywhere in your project)*

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6") )
{
   // do your stuff for iOS >= 6 
}
els
{
  // do your stuff for iOS <= 6
}
```